# How to calculate row using different value from joined table

Tags: sql, join, calculation

I need to run an update on a SQL table, using a value from a different (but almost identical) row in the same table, to show how different sales scenarios play out.

e.g.

```
Starting with:
ITEM, SITE, SUPPLIER, SCENARIO, SALES_VOLUME, PRICE, TOTAL_SALES
1   , A   , X       , S1      , 100         , 10   , 1000
2   , A   , Y       , S1      , 25          , 20   , 500
1   , A   , X       , S2      , {blank}     , 20   , 0 

I would like to update to show:
ITEM, SITE, SUPPLIER, SCENARIO, SALES_VOLUME, PRICE, TOTAL_SALES
1   , A   , X       , 1       , 100         , 10   , 1000
2   , A   , Y       , 1       , 25          , 20   , 500
1   , A   , X       , 2       , {blank}     , 20   , 2000
```

So basically, if SCENARIO = S2, I need to recalculate using SALES_VOLUME where SCENARIO = S1

I tried the following, but it didn't work - I think because I'm trying to specify both =1 and !=1 in the same lookup.

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET [TOTAL_SALES]   = (t1.[PRICE] * t2.[SALES_VOLUME])
FROM TABLE1 t1
inner join TABLE1 t2
    on  t1.[ITEM]       = t2.[ITEM]
    and t1.[SITE]       = t2.[SITE]
    and t1.[SUPPLIER]   = t2.[SUPPLIER]
    and t1.[SCENARIO]   = 'S1'
WHERE   t1.[SCENARIO]   != 'S1'
```

I don't think I'm too far off, but just feel I'm missing something.

Any pointers would be gratefully received.  :)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this -

```
UPDATE t1
SET [TOTAL_SALES]   = (t1.[PRICE] * t2.[SALES_VOLUME])
FROM TABLE1 t1
inner join TABLE1 t2
    on  t1.[ITEM]       = t2.[ITEM]
    and t1.[SITE]       = t2.[SITE]
    and t1.[SUPPLIER]   = t2.[SUPPLIER]
    and t1.[SCENARIO]   = 'S2'
  WHERE t2.[SCENARIO]   = 'S1';
```

Comment: Thanks.
It was the table reference that was messing me up in the first row.
I reversed your last 2 entries and it worked.